# geopandas point in polygon

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, point-in-polygon

I have a GeoDataFrame of polygons (~30) and a GeoDataFrame of Points (~10k)

I'm looking to create 30 new columns (with appropriate polygon names) in my GeoDataFrame of Points with a simple boolean True/False if the point is present in the polygon.

As an example, the GeoDataFrame of Polygons is this:

```
id  geometry
foo POLYGON ((-0.18353,51.51022, -0.18421,51.50767, -0.18253,51.50744, -0.1794,51.50914))
bar POLYGON ((-0.17003,51.50739, -0.16904,51.50604, -0.16488,51.50615, -0.1613,51.5091))
```

The GeoDataFrame of Points is like this:

```
counter     points
   1     ((-0.17987,51.50974))
   2     ((-0.16507,51.50925))
```

Expected output:

```
counter          points        foo    bar
   1    ((-0.17987,51.50974))  False  False
   1    ((-0.16507,51.50925))  False  False
```

I can do this manually by:

```
foo = df_poly.loc[df_poly.id=='foo']
df_points['foo'] = df_points['points'].map(lambda x: True if foo.contains(x).any()==True else False
```

But given that I have 30 polygons, I was wondering if there is a better way.
Appreciate any help!

Comment: simplify the geometries so I can copy/paste this into a notebook

Comment: @PaulH Updated the question with the polygon details. Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Not really clear what kind of data structures you actually have. Also, all your expected results are False, so that's kind of hard to check. Assuming GeoSeries and GeoDataFrames, I would do this:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
import geopandas

polys = geopandas.GeoSeries({
    'foo': Polygon([(5, 5), (5, 13), (13, 13), (13, 5)]),
    'bar': Polygon([(10, 10), (10, 15), (15, 15), (15, 10)]),
})

_pnts = [Point(3, 3), Point(8, 8), Point(11, 11)]
pnts = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(geometry=_pnts, index=['A', 'B', 'C'])
pnts = pnts.assign(**{key: pnts.within(geom) for key, geom in polys.items()})

print(pnts)
```

And that gives me:

```
        geometry    bar    foo
A    POINT (3 3)  False  False
B    POINT (8 8)  False   True
C  POINT (11 11)   True   True
```

Comment: Nice answer! I wonder, how would you do this so that instead that each key is a column, there's a single column and the content is the key rather than a True/False?

Comment: @Manhattan points can be in more than one polygon, so that model breaks down if you want to keep your (geo)dataframe tidy http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf. That said, you could simply `melt` this dataframe and query out the false values.

Comment: Aha, nice use of `melt`. Thanks!

Comment: It fails for Point(35.68333333, 139.75)   & Polygon([(90,0),(0,180),(0,-180)])

Comment: @pksingh an important nuance of `shapely` is that it's for geometric, not geographic operations. In other words, `Polygon([(90,0),(0,180),(0,-180)]` is a triangle, not a hemisphere

Comment: Thanks @PaulH , is there a direct way for the same?

Comment: @jolly you need to project your lat/lon into a UTM or other projected coordinate system. BTW, what you mean by 
"fails"? Do you mean, raises an error or returns an unexpected result? In planar coordinates your point is outside of your triangle.

Comment: Thanks @PaulH , Fail is exactly what you said. Point is indeed outside 2d triangle. But is there a way to check if it is inside 3d triangle

Comment: @jolly `shapely` is for planar geometries. I don't work with volumes so I can't help you there.

Comment: For this nice example given by Paul, I get an error:


AttributeError: 'GeoSeries' object has no attribute 'items'
  File "<ipython-input-346-b0e1c3e220d9>", line 11, in <module>
    pnts = pnts.assign(**{key: pnts.within(geom) for key, geom in polys.items()})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3077, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'GeoSeries' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: @SolomonVimal which versions of geopandas and pandas do you have? This still works for me on geopandas v0.4.0 and pandas v0.24.1

Comment: I have geopandas==0.3.0+48.ga577b12 & geopandas-osm==0.0.1 & pandas==0.20.3
Not sure why it isn't working for me.

Comment: the error is coming from pandas, so upgrade that first

Comment: I can try to upgrade mine to your version.

Comment: Now I have geopandas==0.4.0 and geopandas-osm==0.0.1 and pandas==0.24.1, and it works! Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this could alternatively be done with `sjoin` and then `pivot`? https://geopandas.org/en/stable/gallery/spatial_joins.html#Joins