# Determine if geopandas point is in generic polygon with holes

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, point-in-polygon

This thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48097742/geopandas-point-in-polygon) gave a solution of how to determine if a `geopandas` `POINT` is in a solid `POLYGON`.

What would be a generic solution to determine this for a `POLYGON` with holes, i.e. `MULTIPOLYGON`.

For e.g., using `foo` below:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
import geopandas

polys = geopandas.GeoSeries({
    'foo': Polygon([(5, 5), (5, 13), (13, 13), (13, 5)],
                        [[(7, 7), (7, 11), (11, 11), (11, 7)]]),
    'bar': Polygon([(10, 10), (10, 15), (15, 15), (15, 10)]),
})

_pnts = [Point(3, 3), Point(8, 8), Point(11, 11)]
pnts = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(geometry=_pnts, index=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Strictly the sample you have provided are polygons.  Geometry contains a hole.

It's pretty straight forward to test,  just use **convex_hull**. Code below does both tests.

```
pnts.assign(
    **{
        **{key: pnts.within(geom) for key, geom in polys.items()},
        **{key+"_filled": pnts.within(geom.convex_hull) for key, geom in polys.items()},
    }
)
```

|  | geometry | foo | bar | foo_filled | bar_filled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | POINT (3 3) | False | False | False | False |
| B | POINT (8 8) | False | False | True | False |
| C | POINT (11 11) | False | True | True | True |