# Mapping lat long to boundary of lat longs in another file in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I have two data frames -

df1 - columns are Order_ID, lat, long

| Order_ID | Lat | Long |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 32.0455 | -76.9876 |
| 2 | 32.5679 | -77.3421 |
| 3 | 33.4567 | -77.9876 |

df2 - columns are lat, long, Category

| Category | Lat | Long |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | 32.0109 | -76.0765 |
| S1 | 32.8769 | -77.5674 |
| S1 | 33.1987 | -78.7654 |
| S2 | 33.5967 | -78.0765 |
| S2 | 33.8769 | -79.5674 |
| S2 | 34.1987 | -79.7654 |

df1 is order level data with latitude and longitude present for each order.

df2 would have multiple lat long for each category, essentially defining a boundary in map for each category separately.

I want to map order id to category id. For example, based on the polygon of S1 or S2, order id would lie in one of the category.

How can I map the order_id in df1 to category in df2. Please help with dummy python pandas code.

Comment: please share what `df1` and `df2` look like and what you've tried so far. potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48097742/geopandas-point-in-polygon

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

- I have tried with your sample data.  There are not enough orders such that the convex hull of the points *cover* any category
- have simulated some data to demonstrate

  1. create **geopandas** data frame of orders
  2. create **geopandas** data frame of convex hull of points that make up categories
  3. `sjoin()` two *GeoDataFrames* to find association you require
- have provided a visualisation to better demonstrate how this works

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_cities"))
gdf = gdf.loc[gdf["name"].isin(["London", "Paris", "Brussels"])]
# gdf = gdf.sample(10)

# pandas dataframes structured as per question
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Long": gdf["geometry"].x, "Lat": gdf["geometry"].y, "Order_ID": gdf["name"]}
)
N = 8
df2 = pd.concat(
    [
        pd.DataFrame(
            {
                "Long": np.random.uniform(r.minx, r.maxx, N),
                "Lat": np.random.uniform(r.miny, r.maxy, N),
                "Category": np.full(N, chr(65 + _)),
            }
        )
        for _, r in gdf.reset_index()
        .to_crs(gdf.estimate_utm_crs())
        .buffer(3 * 10**5)
        .to_crs(gdf.crs)
        .bounds.iterrows()
    ]
)

# sample geometry,  not enough orders to work effectively
# df1 = pd.DataFrame(
#     **{
#         "index": [0, 1, 2],
#         "columns": ["Order_ID", "Lat", "Long"],
#         "data": [[1, 32.0455, -76.9876], [2, 32.5679, -77.3421], [3, 33.4567, -77.987]],
#     }
# )

# df2 = pd.DataFrame(
#     **{
#         "index": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
#         "columns": ["Category", "Lat", "Long"],
#         "data": [
#             ["S1", 32.0109, -76.0765],
#             ["S1", 32.8769, -77.5674],
#             ["S1", 33.1987, -78.7654],
#             ["S2", 33.5967, -78.0765],
#             ["S2", 33.8769, -79.5674],
#             ["S2", 34.1987, -79.7654],
#         ],
#     }
# )

gdf1 = gpd.gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df1["Order_ID"],
    geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(x=df1["Long"], y=df1["Lat"]),
    crs="epsg:4386",
)

# want convex hull of all points that make up a category
gdf2 = (
    gpd.GeoDataFrame(
        df2["Category"],
        geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(x=df2["Long"], y=df2["Lat"]),
        crs="epsg:4386",
    )
    .dissolve("Category")
    .convex_hull.reset_index()
)

# get association between order and category using geometry
gpd.sjoin(gdf1, gdf2)
```

|  | Order_ID | geometry | index_right | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 158 | Brussels | POINT (4.33137074969045 50.83526293533032) | 0 | A |
| 187 | London | POINT (-0.118667702475932 51.5019405883275) | 1 | B |
| 199 | Paris | POINT (2.33138946713035 48.86863878981461) | 2 | C |

#### visualise

```
# visualise it...
m = gdf2.explore(height=300, width=500)
gdf1.explore(m=m, color="red")
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting this error when I configured this for my use case. Error - ValueError: 'right_df' should be GeoDataFrame, got <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>. I am using the last bit of your code (sjoin) and loading the dfs as pandas df.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this but for gdf2, I am still getting this error - ValueError: 'right_df' should be GeoDataFrame, got <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>. Somehow, it is considering gdf2 as pandas df instead of GeoDf.

Comment: error is exactly what it says .... `sjoin()` only works on geodataframes.   hence reason I have created `gdf1` and `gdf2` from `df1` and `df2` respectively ...